# Java: Cannot get two ArrayLists not to be "connected"

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm practicing for UIL when I come across a problem: my ArrayLists, for some odd reason, share the same value with each other. They are both declared as Characters, although declared as different objects, and I cannot figure out a way to separate them.

What I want done is one of them will be a base, while the other one changes throughout the nested loop, however, they both change, even though I don't change the base one after I set it, and I cannot figure out why. I found my answer a bit ago explaining that the main method is static so they point to the same place, but after making a new class and then making an object in the main method to do it it still won't work.

Can anybody explain to me as to why they are connected?

`````````````
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Boggle 
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Throwable
    {
        Boggle test = new Boggle();
        test.theBoggle();
    }

    public void theBoggle() throws Throwable
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("boggle.dat"));
        int games = scan.nextInt();
        int amtofwords = 0;
        int puzzle = 1;
        boolean possible = true;
        boolean possibleletter = false;
        String tempword = "";
        int pointcounter = 0;
        ArrayList<Character> scrambled = new ArrayList<Character>(); 
        ArrayList<Character> testscramble = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        scan.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < games; i++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < 4; w++)
            {
                tempword = scan.nextLine();
                scrambled.add(tempword.charAt(0));
                scrambled.add(tempword.charAt(1));
                scrambled.add(tempword.charAt(2));
                scrambled.add(tempword.charAt(3));
            }
            amtofwords = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            for (int k = 0; k < amtofwords; k++)
            {
                words.add(scan.nextLine());
            }
            for (String string : words) //grabs the words
            {
                possible = true;
                testscramble = scrambled; //````````````IMPORTANT WHY ARE THEY BOTH CONNECTED?``````````
                System.out.println(scrambled);
                for (int k = 0; k < string.length(); k++) //grabs the scrambled letters to compare to string
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < testscramble.size(); j++) //grabs individual letters to compare to word
                    {
                        if (string.charAt(k) == testscramble.get(j))
                        {
                            possibleletter = true;
                            testscramble.remove(j);

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (possibleletter == false)
                    {
                        possible = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    possibleletter = false;

                }
                if (possible == true)
                {
                    if (string.length() <= 2)
                        pointcounter += 0;
                    if (string.length() == 3 || string.length() == 4)
                        pointcounter += 1;
                    if (string.length() == 5)
                        pointcounter += 2;
                    if (string.length() == 6)
                        pointcounter += 3;
                    if (string.length() == 7)
                        pointcounter += 5;
                    if (string.length() >= 8)
                        pointcounter += 11;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("PUZZLE #" + puzzle + " " + pointcounter);
            puzzle++;

        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
`````````````

Comment: I'm printing out scrambled, which is exactly the values of testscramble, although I never change scrambled

Comment: Well...you've just said that `testscramble` points to the same entity as `scrambled`...are you asking why `testscramble = scrambled` works the way it does, or were you expecting different behavior from that?

Comment: What do you think `testscramble = scrambled` does? Now you have two references to the same list. So obviously, if you add an object to the list using one reference, the other reference points to the same, modified list.

Comment: Damn I totally forgot that that is what that does! What is the way so they don't connect like that and instead just have the same values?

Comment: It's pretty early, so I'm still waking up haha

Comment: `testscramble = new ArrayList<>(scrambled)`.

Comment: Thank you Boris the Spider! Damn, I really screwed up there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you used references to convert one list variable into a reference to another list variable

```
testscramble = scramble;
```

when you should have copied the list as such

```
testscramble = new ArrayList<>(scrambled);
```